# casting string to json and ordering by value as int

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-order-by, aggregate

I have a string field in my database that contains a JSON value. I can sort the rows by this value by casting to `json` and accessing the value, like so:

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY stringvalue::json->>'key' ASC
```

However, this will sort alphabetically, but the 'key' contains a numeric value, so instead of 1-2-...-10-11 it will go 1-10-11-2-...

The documentation suggests that `(jsonvalue->>'m148')::int ASC` should work, but I get "aggregate function needs to appear in grouping column" when trying this, I guess due to the fact that I don't have a `json` field, but a string field that I'm already casting to `json`;

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY (stringvalue::json->>'key')::int ASC
```

Any suggestions on how I would keep this format of casting to `json` while also sorting numerically?

Comment: Please post your exact error message/code and your whole query, if these examples are just simplification of those. Your select in its state should work (however not the best practice to store json in its string form).

Comment: Obviously, you are running a different query with aggregate functions. You question doesn't make sense with the query you present.

Answer (score 0):

JSON can only be sorted numerically or otherwise with the introduction of JSON Binary in Postgres 9.4, but since we're not on that version my workaround will be 0-padding the int. '0001' > '0011' and all is well.